# rails show and save 1-to-n relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have two models like [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association), where my `Order` model `belongs_to` model `Section`

My form looks like this:

```rb
= form_for @section do |s|
  - @section.orders.group_by(&:customer_id).each do |order, customers|
    = s.text_field :customer
    = s.fields_for :orders, customers.sort_by(&:id) do |custm|
      = pd.text_field
```

Any customer can have up to 3 orders.
My question is how do I save the data, considering that I need the new customer_id before saving orders into database?

Comment: see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: It seems to me that you have another model here, which you didn't say a word about: `Customer`. How does it relates to other two models?

Comment: The relationship is Section->Order (1:N) and Order->Customer (N:1). Customer haves `has_many :orders` and Order haves `belongs_to :customer`

Answer (score 0):

You need a submit button.  Something like:

```
s.submit
```

Check out [form_helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) for more info

Comment: He would also need some `end`s in the code - it is obviously only a part of whole form.